# Graph formatting in AndroidPlot

Tags: android, graph, androidplot

I have implemented ECG output as graph using AndroidPlot. When new data arrives I need a formatter to clear previous data one by one. Please check this link to make it more clear https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G15xQejYNQs (my requirement starts at 0.50 sec in this video). How can I achieve it?

[image] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to achieving this kind of behavior is implementing your XYSeries as a circular buffer.  Androidplot provides a full [sample implementation of an ECG using a circular buffer](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/demoapp/src/main/java/com/androidplot/demos/ECGExample.java).